# Reference to content type

Tags: nodes, 7, entities

I have multiple content types for consumer electronics goods, like "tv", "laptop", "mouse" etc. Every content type has its own fields and exposed using contexts and views with custom facet api blocks – "catalog/tv", "catalog/laptop" etc. The number of content types is more than 100 and growing.

I need to display custom blocks with description and images for each content type which would be displayed on the catalog pages with facets. The common way is to create block and manage the visibility with contexts or block interface. But it is to tricky for content managers, there is big possibility of errors and also I get 100+ blocks.

So I want to create custom content type which nodes would be displayed with contextual views on facet pages. But how to link node to content type?

Comment: You should use https://drupal.org/project/entityreference (node reference) module.

Comment: How can I reference to content type with this module?